# How to avoid array index out of bounds exception when using JSONObject's has function

Tags: java, android, json, socket.io

I'm working on an android project in which I'm using `Socket.io`.

I have a `JSONObject` which I get from the server (source code is written below).

Here, I need to check for a key from the `JSONObject` to display the UI. If my `JSONObject` has a particular key, I'll proceed ahead else I'll be hitting the server continuously using a while loop. When I get that particular key i'm getting `array index out of bound exception`  sometimes(this doesn't happen every time) and for the rest of times it is not displaying any error and the output is as expected. Kindly request you to check my source code and help me where I'm going wrong.

Source Code:

```
socket tmp = new socket();
In Login.class  
JSONObject ca = tmp.countActiveChallenge();

while(!ca.has("myKey")){
 JSONObject ca = tmp.countActiveChallenge();
}
```

In socket.class
I return a jsonobject with that particular key
[image: I'm attaching a screen shot of the logcat error][image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Index is negative in the log, so you should start by checking how the index gets set. Also, format your JSON in JSONLint and share, these screenshots are not very readable.

Answer (score 0):

There is something seriously strange going on there.  A `HashMap` shouldn't throw that exception.  The only explanations I can think of are:

- Your application has a race condition caused by two threads reading / updating that `HashMap` object without proper synchronization.
- Something is using reflection to tinker with the `HashMap`'s internal data structures.
- There's a bug in `HashMap` for that version of Android.

The first explanation is the most likely, IMO.  I expect that `tmp.countActiveChallenge()` is returning a reference to a `JSONObject` that some other thread is updating.  Clearly, this part of the code is not synchronizing ...

---

I don't think there is a good solution using `JSONObject`.  The best you could do would be to change this code, and the code that updates the map to synchronize externally.  But that is likely to lead to contention issues, especially if there are lots of entries.

Maybe a better alternative would be to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of a `JSONObject`.